# if with jquery returning undefined and not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am opening dropdowns in bootstrap by adding show to their elements, which works fine. I am also trying to close other dropdowns that are open, which is what this function does.
My function:

```
  function classremove() {
    var doesithavetheclass = $('div').hasClass('show');
    if (doesithavetheclass == 'true') {
      $('div').removeClass('show');
    };
    return doesithavetheclass;
  };
```

The `if` is the part that won't work. Running the code inside the `if` works, and defining the variable in the Chrome console works properly, but running the `if` inside of the Chrome console doesn't work even if before I defined the variable with dropdowns open with the show class.

Comment: Don't compare a Boolean value to a string. `if (doesithavetheclass)` is what you want.

Comment: @mercator Thanks! That fixed it!

Comment: But also note imvain2's answer. `removeClass` will simply not do anything if the class isn't there to begin with, so you don't really need to do this check at all.

Comment: Yeah, I had a very stupid issue because it would close all of the dropdowns, but I had a toggleClass on it so it would never close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The if statement and most of that function is really not needed. You can simplify to only remove the class.

```
function classremove() {
      $('div').removeClass('show');
  };
```